# Excel execute function when cell is clicked

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to execute a formula when a cell is clicked or get adress of selected cell and then if it matches execute formula without using VBA?

Answer (score 0):

There is something that *almost* does want you want natively in Excel without VBA.

The CELL function allows you to access some (fairly limited) information about a particular cell. If you choose, you can direct the function to give you information about a particular cell, or you can let the function give you information *about the last cell which had information entered in it*.

For example, the following tells you the width of cell A1:

```
=CELL("width",A1)
```

Whereas the following (without a second argument provided) tells you the address of the last cell where data was entered:

```
=CELL("address")
```

For your purposes, you can use this information in other formulas to act based on where you have most recently entered data, like so:

```
=IF(CELL("address") = "$A$1", "A1 was the last cell entered!", "")
```